# Looking for java 1.6 workaround to apparent compiler issue

Tags: java, generics, guava, java-6

This compiles fine with Java 1.7 but not with 1.6. (This is using Guava 14.0.1).

```
Cache<TokenCacheKey, CachedToken>tokenCache = CacheBuilder.<TokenCacheKey, CachedToken>from(PARAM.tokenCacheConfig).build();
```

Can anyone suggest an alternative that can be compiled in 1.6?

Comment: Can you include the message you get when compilation fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`CacheBuilder#from(CacheBuilderSpec)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#from%28com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilderSpec%29) is not a generic method. It seems, pre-Java 7, you could not provide type arguments to non-generic methods.

Just remove the type arguments

```
Cache<TokenCacheKey, CachedToken> tokenCache = CacheBuilder.from(PARAM.tokenCacheConfig).build();
```